# How to run docpad over ssl?

Tags: ssl, https, docpad

I want to let users to access all the site's pages using both http and https.

I also want to be able to redirect http requests for certain paths (/api/* and /backend/*) that require encryption to https (force https).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node version: v0.9.10

docpad version: v6.21.10

Important note: It seems that the documentation for the [docpad config file](http://docpad.org/docs/config) is outdated, I had to dig the source to find that the serverHttp and serverExpress options now have to be under the server option.

here's the project's [docpad.js](http://docpad.org/docs/config) file:

```
var https = require('https'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs'),
express = require('express');

var sslOptions = {
                  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../certificates/key.pem")),
                  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../certificates/cert.pem"))
              };

serverExpress = express();
serverHttps = https.createServer(sslOptions, serverExpress);

docpadConfig = {
    environments: {
        http: {
            port: 80,
            events: {
                serverExtend: function (server) {
                    var i = 0;

                    // Redirect requests that requires https
                    server.server.get(/^\/(api|backend)\/.*/, function (req, res) {
                        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        https: {
            port: 443,
            server: {
                serverHttp: serverHttps,
                serverExpress: serverExpress
            }
        }
    }
};

module.exports = docpadConfig;
```

Run the two environments with:

```
docpad --env "http" run
docpad --env "https" run
```

and that's it.

Comment: Man this is awesome. I love your environment based approach. Great work! Re "I had to dig the source to find that the serverHttp and serverExpress options now have to be under the server option." seems like a bug, created an issue for it here: https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/457

Comment: I'm glad you liked it :) Thank you for developing docpad.